# Can I install Ubuntu, Python and Redis in one Docker container?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I am doing a project with regard to fog computing. I would like to use one docker container to simulate a fog node which can process data, store data in the database and send data to Cloud. I need Ubuntu, Python, and Redis to develop my application.

I was wondering is it possible to install them in a single container? Because I can only install them separately in different containers by using 'docker pull' command.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Best practise is to have them communicate to each other using docker networking, instead of install all in one container.

Comment: One problem with this question is that "Ubuntu" isn't a service that runs a container.  You could have a an image *based on* Ubuntu that runs a Python service, or an image *based on* Ubuntu that runs Redis, etc.  You would generally put each service in a separate container.

Comment: You can do that but many people will argue that you should have only one service per container. In any case you will need at least one Dockerfile which takes the Ubuntu base image of your choice and extends it with your Python application and Redis. If you decide to use two containers, have a look at `docker-compose`. It  helps you run and manage containers as a group. Unluckily your question is too unspecific to make a good answer out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad practice and very time consuming. Anyway if you really want to go down that way you have to create your own image, follow the instructions to install Redis and put each step inside the your new Dockerfile (or you can try to adapt the redis Dockerfile -  https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/99a06c057297421f9ea46934c342a2fc00644c4f/3.2/Dockerfile).

Once this is done, you simply add the new commands to install python and build.

Good luck.